# How do I get a video-entry's RSS "description" via the API?

Tags: youtube

I used to use the RSS feed to obtain videos from a user. I then used the "description" part of the feed, which contained a nicely HTML-formatted summary of a video. It shows a thumbnail with a link, time of video, username, star rating, etc.

Example:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/KeepWatchingTheSkies/uploads?alt=rss&v=2&orderby=published&client=ytapi-youtube-profile (Search for second  tag)

Now I'm trying to use the YouTube API (through the `gdata` Python interface,) and I'm able to retrieve the video entries, but I can't figure out how to get this "description" that I used to get through the RSS feeds.

How can I do this?

Comment: I found a workaround, I'm not interested in an answer for this question anymore, thanks.

Comment: It would have been nice to have you post your work around instead of running off rudely

Answer (score 3):

```
import gdata.youtube
import gdata.alt.appengine
import gdata.youtube.service

class Index(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        client = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
        feed = client.GetRecentlyFeaturedVideoFeed()
        gdata.alt.appengine.run_on_appengine(client)

        self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
        for entry in feed.entry:
            self.response.out.write('<div>%s</div>' %entry.media.description)
        self.response.out.write('</html></body>')
```

If you are using a rendering template like Django, instead of self response call the rendering function of the template and pass the variable feed, in your html file call Django variables like this:

replace the self.response with:

```
templates.render(self, 'home.html',
                    feed=feed,
                 )
```

and add to your html:

```
{% for entry in feed.entry %}
    <div>{{entry.media.description}}</div>
{% endfor %}
```